# FIND command to find files and exclude one subdirectory

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find the `*.mxf` and `*.MOV` files with One Directory which are older than `14 days`but i want to exclude one sub directory named as `Secure` within this search. here is my command , which i am using it but i am also seeing the files from `Secure` directory which is not supposed to be here.

```
find /main/videos/internal/files/ ! -path "/main/videos/internal/file/Secure/*" \ 
      -type f -name '*.mxf' -o -name '*.MOV' -mtime +14
```

please guys help me to find out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `! -path "/main/videos/internal/file/Secure/*"` will avoid subdirectories under `/main/videos/internal/file/Secure/` only, not any other `Secure` directory in the hierarchy involved here. For example, `/main/videos/internal/file/foobar/Secure/spam.MOV` will still show up in the output.

So if you want to exclude all `Secure` directories (and subdirectories), you can use the `-prune` action of `find` here :

```
find /main/videos/internal/files/ -type d -name 'Secure' -prune -o \ 
      -type f \( -name '*.mxf' -o -name '*.MOV' \) -mtime +14 -print
```

To match the files you can use `-regex` :

```
find /main/videos/internal/files/ -type d -name 'Secure' -prune -o \ 
      -type f -regex '.*\.\(mxf\|MOV\)$' -mtime +14 -print
```

Comment: thanks for the response, 

i have tried all three but these commands give me this same error.
`find: paths must precede expression:  -type
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
`

Comment: @kunal That means you probably have changed something..what command did you run exactly ? DId you remove the quotes ?

Comment: `find /main/videos/internal/files/ -not -path \ '/main/videos/internal/files/Secure/*' \ -type f -name '*.mxf' -o -name '*.MOV' -mtime +14
`

Comment: @kunal Remove the two `\\`s ..i put it because my command spans two lines..

Comment: ah thanks now i get the result , but i am still seeing in the result files from Secure Folder.

note: There are also sub directories within `Secure` DIR, I want to exclude this Secure Sub Dir totally

Comment: @kunal check the input, output path of `Secure` and spelling..could you add some examples to your question..also try using `prune` ..

Comment: But just want to tell you that i have tried your Second Suggestion and it worked perfect

Comment: Prune option is working Good.

Comment: @kunal My guess is that it is coming from other parts of hierarchy that has `Secure` in their names..glad it worked :)

Comment: @kunal Check my edits please..

Comment: I did , my all typing mistake you have edited ;)